# Merge multiple configuration file in Yii

Tags: configuration, yii2

My Yii application consists of 4 modules. Each module has its own config file main.php listing configuration for only url manager.I have all other configurations inside /config/main.php of application directory. Is there a solution to mere each of the modules configuration into main configuration file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your using `Yii 1 or 2`. Your question says `Yii` but is tagged as `yii2`.

If its Yii 1, then try this -

You have 4 modules. They must be located at 

`/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME1`, `/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME2`, and the other two.

Each module having its own `main.php` consists of array for `UrlManager`.
Lets say you have a `config` folder in each `MODULE_NAME` folder and `main.php` in it.

So the location becomes - `/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME1/config/main.php`.

Now, in the `index.php`, you must be having a line of code as `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';`

This is how the `main.php`(`located at /protected/config/main.php`) data is fetched.

So if you want to add more config arrays, then just fetch each of them and merge with the primary one.

Eg:

```
$config = array_merge(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php'),
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME1/config/main.php'),
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME2/config/main.php'),
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME3/config/main.php'),
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/modules/MODULE_NAME4/config/main.php'),
);
```

Make sure the `arrays` returned from the Module's `main.php` have the same structure for `urlManager`.

Comment: Just in-case its Yii2, please let me know.